# Calling webservice from JavaScript has no effect

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, web-services

i am drawing data table from data base , one of its column is delete which i want on its click to apply a code which exists in webservice and this is my code in C# is

```
  "<a target='_blank' href=\'javascript:void(0)\' onclick=\"Delete_exam('" + id + "')\" style='text-align:center; font-family:Tahoma; font-size:15px; ' title='download' class='with-tip' >" + "تحميل" + "</a>"
```

and in java script is

```
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="script1" runat="server">
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/WebService.asmx" />
    </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function Delete_exam(Id)
    {
         WebService.Delete_Exam(Id, Delete_Exam_Sucess, Delete_Exam_Failed);
    }

    function Delete_Exam_Scess(result)
    {
        if (result == 0) {
            alert("Done");
        }
        else {
            alert(result);
        }
    }

    function Delete_Exam_Failed()
    {
        alert("failed");
    }
</script>
```

but this code didn't run webservice.

Comment: In the string, why are you escaping single quotes in `\'javascript:void(0)\'` when you can actually just write `'javascript:void(0)'`? Are you getting any error messages when clicking the button?

Comment: You do know you've mis-spelled your success function as well ? Delete_Exam_Sucess - Delete_Exam_Scess ?

Comment: the problem is how to enter to webservice , sucess  and failed function , it is test code